# tmux, bash, and .bashrc

Tags: bash, tmux

So, basically, when `tmux` launches, what all does it run through to start up?

I recently changed the location of my home directory on a few servers, CentOS and Ubuntu. I also use `tmux` and `bash`.

I noticed when I launch `tmux`, it loads a bare `bash` shell, not running my `bashrc`, but it does load my `tmux.conf`. `echo $HOME` shows my old home directory.

When I'm logged in through SSH, not in `tmux`, it loads `bashrc` just fine, and my `$HOME` is my new home directory.

What does `tmux` run through when loading, and what would be reading my old home directory for `$HOME`?

The home directory is changed in the `/etc/passwd`, I've tried using `usermod` to write the change that way, it responds with 'no changes'.

Would like to get this worked out. Have already searched around, can't find much. Thanks.

Comment: $HOME is typically set by the login program and left unchanged by shells. This seems to be correct for you if you login via ssh. Tmux reads it's config file, and that can specify environment variables and the program(s) to run. So the next step would be to try renaming /etc/tmux.conf and ~/.tmux.conf and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Moved ~/.tmux.conf elsewhere, still same result.
/etc/tmux.conf does not exist. All that tmux installed was the binary in /usr/bin and examples in the /usr/share/doc and documentation in /usr/share/man

Answer (score 0):

Add the line:

```
 set-option update-environment $HOME
```

to the ~/.tmux.conf file

Comment: Should that not be just `HOME`?

Comment: It works with both